# How can I get the most smoke flavor from Lapsang Souchong tea?

Tags: flavor, tea, smoke-flavor

When I open a bag of Lapsang Souchong tea, it has an overpowering aroma of pine smoke. After brewing, there is still a smokiness in my drink but it is far more subtle, and in particular seems to vary fairly widely from cup to cup.

I wonder what factors would cause this inconsistent extraction, and, more to the point, how I could focus my efforts to tweak the final product. For example, if I steep hotter, or cooler, or longer, or shorter, or covered, or stirred, etc.

Comment: How are you currently steeping it? Personally, I steep Lapsang in boiled water for 5min.

Comment: Wiki says Formosan (Taiwanese) lapsang has the smokiest flavour, perhaps you could find some?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, that is good to know, but I am interested from a process perspective.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing would be an experiment or two. Use the same amount of tea and water and steep three cups for three different times etc

Answer (score 3):

For overall full-flavor, these instructions produce the best cup:

> Use a teapot and cup made from glass, or other material like
>   porcelain. Use soft water for preparation of tea. This is suitable to
>   effectively extract most of the substances from the tea leaves. Hard
>   water is not suitable because it contains higher levels of mineral
>   ions which suppress extraction of substances from leaves,
>   subsequently, the taste become very flat and thin. Besides, mineral
>   ions react with polyphenols substances which will give a dark brown
>   color. Use fresh water which has not boiled before. Bring the cold
>   water to boil, and then pour in boiling water that has been freshly
>   drawn which the temperature is > 95˚C.=Boiling Temparature. Warm the
>   teapot and cups well by rinsing it out with boiling water. This should
>   be done just before adding the tea leaves, so that the leaves benefit
>   from a gentle humid heat. For black tea, the main component is tannin
>   which required high temperature for efficacious extraction. It is
>   necessary to keep container warm in order to maintain* adequate
>   temperature in brewing water.

Got that off this site promoting their LS tea from the Wuyi Mountain area of Fujian where I have toured and sampled: http://hojotea.com/item_e/b02e.htm 
The part about only boiling *once* should not be underestimated: tea needs the oxygen to react and release those magical substances.

Have you experimented with second brewing? Drink the first cuppa after a short brew and cover with water again and see if that is indeed smokier.